# Cannot delete Steam, path leads to wrong disk

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, uninstall, steam, windows-error-reporting

So I am trying to delete Steam.  When I do so I get the error:

> Windows cannot find 'C:\program Files (x86)\Steam\uninstall.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

The problem is that Steam is not located on the `C:` drive but the `D:` drive.
I've had similar problems since the last Windows update, but I have solved the problems multiple times by changing the directory in the environment tables.

I've been looking for the Steam directory but can't seem to find it in the menu of the Environment tables.

Comment: Can't you just navigate to the actual installation folder and run the `uninstall.exe` manually?

Comment: @MichaelBay Hmm so I just tried that, The executable works but when I get in the menu of SteamUninstall it says. Uninstalling from C:\programfiles(x86)\steam <br> so It still tries to uninstall from the C drive whilst it is installed on the D

Comment: You may have inadvertently installed Skynet inside of Steam. Unfortunately the only way to fix this is to reinstall the OS, since Steam cannot be deleted or reinstalled. Skynet will prevent you from removing itself from your system. Also keep in mind any other computers on the network could be infected, since Skynet will try to spread itself, and can break through security in a matter of hours.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Can you make a symbolic link from missing Steam directory to the actual one at `D:`.

```
mklink /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam" "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam"
```

The method avoids downloading other utilities and uses the included functionality of the operating system

More about mklink.exe can be found at:
https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html

Comment: To be able to make this symbolic link you are required to open the command prompt as an administrator. Otherwise you will not be allowed to make the link.

Comment: You could improve this answer by (1) rewording it, so it doesn’t look like it’s asking a question, and (2) incorporating Yorick’s comment.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you this utility "Revo Uninstaller".
link: https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html

1.
If you have Steam installed and want it completely removed with everything related (registry, files, links) then run the RevoUninstaller.

There will be a list of installed programs from that list you can select 
 and delete "Steam".

Other solution is that you can click on "Hunter" mode in Revo Uninstaller and drag&drop exe file of program you need to uninstall.

2.You will be asked what type of deletion to choose:
3.Select "Advanced" and click ok/continue.
4.After Revo Uninstaller performs cleanup of uninstaller(if available) it will search for all files and registry entries.
5.Select all files/registry entries for deletion, if they can not be immediately deleted, you will be prompted to choose if you would like that on next reboot (just click ok).

This will completely wipe all data of related to this program.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: I've tried Revo Uninstaller didn't seem to work for the same reason. The uninstall program couldn't actually uninstall steam, because it wasn't located where it thought it was. Thanks for you help.

Comment: thats bad, have you tried Hunter mode with Drag&Drop of exe file onto "Hunter" icon ?

Comment: *because it wasn't located where it thought it was* The only reason for that (and your whole predicament) is incorrect installation. If you installed in the default location *then* moved it to the current location then nothing except symlinking as mentioned in the other answer can possible work. Avoid that by choosing a different location *when* installing.